# PostgreSQL - Extract data no older than 2 days

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have a PostgreSQL database in which I store data that has the following rows:

```
------------------------------------------------------
| id     | did  | sensorid | timestamp | sensor_data |  <-- Column names
------------------------------------------------------ 
| serial | text | int      | bigint    | jsonb       |  <-- Data types
------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to extract data that is no older than 2 days for a query. I have tried the following:

```
SELECT * FROM datastore 
WHERE did = '352204089091070' 
AND timestamp > ((NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') - 172800000);
```

The database contains no index (although I would like it to) but due to the size and the need for the data creating an index right now, would not be the best idea. The timestamp value is in milliseconds (Epoch time) so `172800000` equals two days.

The problem is I have already run through the entire DB and created meta data from old data and now I only want to look at data that is no older than 2 days instead of running through the entire database for each query.

I expect some performance increase compared to my current query which has no limit in timestamp but I just `SELECT` the `MAX(timestamp)` value:

```
SELECT id, did, timestamp, sensor_data FROM datastore
WHERE did = 352204089091070 
AND sensor_id = 910
AND timestamp = (SELECT MAX(timestamp) FROM datastore
                 WHERE did = 352204089091070
                 AND sensor_id = 910)
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

I also tried casting the timezone to `BIGINT` but that doesn't seem to do the trick either.

```
SELECT * FROM datastore 
WHERE did = '352204089091070' 
AND timestamp > ((NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')::BIGINT - 172800000);
```

Sadly I am limited to using PostgreSQL 9.4 and I have not looked into upgrading yet as I don't know what effect it will have on my database yet.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem. If you don't put an index on `timestamp` column (or derived) then every other solution will be either reinventing the wheel or you will lose conistency. Why can't you just index it? Why this is "not the best idea"? If the data is big then you can always use a partial index.

Comment: how do you cast time zone to bigint?

Comment: @freakish Adding an index would mean that the entire database would have to re-index itself making writes to the database impossible (and I need to be able to write to it at all times). And the database is pretty big with around 380 million rows which means the re-indexing of the db would take quite some time.

Comment: @Zeliax That's not true. You can `create index ... concurrently` which does not block writes or reads. Besides 380mln is not that much. Spending few minutes on it is not big deal, right?

Comment: @Zeliax: a `create index` does not lock the "entire database". It **only** locks the _table_ for which you create the index. And it still allows _reading_ from that table during the indexing

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name. Yes I know that. However I am currently utilizing the table which I would need to index, to write and read from as well.

Comment: @freakish I guess you're right. I'll take that into consideration. Thanks for your input ;)

Comment: @VaoTsun I guess that seems to be original problem. I'll try and google that. Thanks for input

Comment: @Zeliax:there is no way you can speed up the query without indexing. You can still allow writes to the table if you create the index concurrently as freakish pointed out.

Comment: probably OP was talking about warming up pages? speed up because subquery is recently selected, so is in RAM?..

Comment: Unrelated, but: to convert a timestamp to an epoch, use `extract()` not casting: `extract(epoch from (NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'))` the cast to `bigint` fails for me in 9.6. Not sure if that was different in 9.4 (I wonder why you didn't use a proper `timestamp` column in the first place, then you could get rid of all that casting)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: The database is very old and I didn't have much of a say when it was created. If I had, I would probably have researched what would be the best way to do it.